# Read Internet Explorer page title with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I have this code

```
    Dim shellWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim strTemp As String
    For Each ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows
            If ie.LocationURL = "Http:\\somelocation" then
                    ie.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", True, vbNull)
                    ie.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, vbNull)
                    strTemp = (Clipboard.GetText())
            End if
    Next
```

However, I need to know the title of this html page. (This page is loaded by javascript and I cannot view the source code. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

The ie.Document.title property should have what you need.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would just retrieve the page as a string and find the Title:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
...
    Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest
    Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse
....
        myRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
        myResponse = CType(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        sr = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
        sResponse = sr.ReadToEnd.ToString
```

Comment: That doesn't work in the scenario he describes, because the JavaScript wouldn't run.